# How to display the 404 error page in Symfony2 dev environment

Tags: symfony, development-environment

I want to work on the 404 page from the dev environment. I customize 404 using this file : **app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig**

This prod url work correctly : `mysite.com/404`

But this one `mysite.com/app_dev.php/404` throw a NotFoundHttpException and give me the dev debug page.

Is it possible to display the error page instead of debug page ?

**UPDATE:**

The official documentation has now a chapter about that : [Testing Error Pages during Development](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#testing-error-pages)

Comment: Override `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/exception.html.twig` as well?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[As of Symfony2.6](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-error-page-previews) in dev environment, you can use the following route:

```
/_error/404.html
```

Where `404` is the error code to test and `html` the format of the request.
To be able to use this features, make sure you have the following entry in your `routing_dev.yml` file:

```
# app/config/routing_dev.yml
_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error
```

Answer (score 22):

To display error pages, in **web/app_dev.php** change second parameter to `false`

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);
```

After testing what you need, change it back.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks @user2019515 for pointing that out - now (2.3 and up) there's a link to [WebfactoryExeptionsBundle](https://github.com/webfactory/exceptions-bundle) in [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) and the method I wrote above should not be used.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go if you want to test your error pages in dev env, as they will be in prod.

Comment: According to the docs, you shouldn't do this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @user2019515. Though, I can't remember now for sure, but when I wrote this answer, there weren't in docs about WebfactoryExceptionsBundle - it appeared with 2.3 documentation.

Answer (score 14):

You need to override the exception_full.html.twig template on development.

```
app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/exception_full.html.twig
```

Symfony2 uses this template to provide you with as much debugging information as possible during development.

When the kernel is in debug mode, Symfony2 will use exception_full.html.twig, otherwise it will use the specific templates you override.

See vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php, specifically the showAction() and findTemplate() functions for more details.

Comment: It seems in Symfony 2.1, the path is:
`vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php`

Comment: I had to `cache:clear` to get the `exception_full.html.twig` to be overridden (SF2.1)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can add routes to your **routing_dev.yml** file

```
error404:
    path: /404
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:    TwigBundle:Exception:error404.html.twig

error500:
    path: /500
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:    TwigBundle:Exception:error500.html.twig
```