# Symfony 2 - Get error instead of debug page on test environment / How to set debug to false on test environment (Twig ExceptionController)?

Tags: symfony

I want to get error page (after an exception of the app is trhown) and not the debug page on testing environment.

I have tracked Twig Bundle code and the answer is in the **Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController** class in the findTemplate() method.
Here I copy the responsible fragment of code that choose the template.

```
    $name = $debug ? 'exception' : 'error';
    if ($debug && 'html' == $format) {
        $name = 'exception_full';
    }
```

There is no problem with this code. The point is that I can't set the ExceptionController **$debug** variable to false for my test environment.

Based on [TwigBundle Configuration Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/configuration/twig.html), it should be enough to set the debug parametar to false in **config_test.yml**.

```
twig:
  debug:       false
```

This is notworking.

I have browsed Symfony code and found this fragment configuration on **vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/config/twig.xml**.

```
    <service id="twig.controller.exception" class="%twig.controller.exception.class%">
        <argument type="service" id="twig" />
        <argument>%kernel.debug%</argument>
    </service>
```

So, no matter what do I set on my configuration files, debug variable value is not modified.

What do you think about it?

I am working with Symfony 2.2.1 and this question is kind of related with [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651403/symfony2-display-404-error-page-in-dev).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this based on the environment?

Like in app_dev.php:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('stag', TRUE); #TRUE = debug/dev mode on
$kernel = new AppKernel('stag', FALSE); #FALSE = debug/dev mode off
```

Comment: Thanks NoScope. It should be based on what you are saying, but It just doesn't work. I'll keep on researching.